# More precise account of map of "deltas" on closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

A while ago, I posted a question on this site: [Is map of "deltas" to points on closed interval continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181131/is-map-of-deltas-to-points-on-closed-interval-continuous), to which I ended up providing an answer to myself.

Since then, my attention has been brought to a counter-example, namely:
$f(x): [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x$. Then $\delta_1(x) = 1$ for $x \in \{0, 1\}$, but $\delta_1(x) = \infty$ otherwise, so $\delta_1(x)$ is not continuous, even though $f(x)$ is.

My question now is whether anyone knows where the proof is wrong. If I look at the counterexample, I think it might be the case that you cannot always choose an $x'$ in the interval where the function is defined such that $x'$ lies within the appropriate radius of $x_1$ but not $x_0$ (or vice versa) - in the example all $x \in [0, 1]$ are within $\delta_1(0)$ of $0$ and $\delta_1(x), x \in (0,1)$, even though $\delta_1(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$.

This might need to be a separate question, but can anybody answer whether there is anything general we can say about the behaviour of the function $\delta_{\epsilon}(x)$ for a given $f(x)$, depending on $\epsilon$?

Thank you!

Comment: To me taking the sup seems like a weird thing to do. The actual interesting property of $D_\epsilon$ is that if $\delta_1 \in D_\epsilon$ and $\delta_2 \leq \delta_1$ everywhere then $\delta_2 \in D_\epsilon$. You can use this to regularize a discontinuous choice of $\delta$.

Comment: I think it is much more natural to allow only deltas from $[0,1]$, so that $\delta_1(x) = 1$ everywhere.

Comment: In general I think you can cook up lots of scenarios where $\delta_\epsilon$ jumps to $\infty$ even on unbounded domains, so the fact that this domain is bounded seems to not be the problem (and so simply redefining things so that it's the supremum on $[0,D]$ where $D$ is the diameter doesn't fix the problem in general). Consider something like $\arctan$ where $\epsilon$ is between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, then $\delta_\epsilon$ will have an *interior* jump to $\infty$ and then another interior jump from $\infty$.

Comment: But as I said in my first comment, you can take this "plateau at infinity" and just drag it down to a finite value to get a continuous version.

Comment: @Ian thanks, these are really useful insights.